# SSAS Role setup

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence

I have a user that needs to have access to 2 different countries and based on that value a member set of another attribute is filled.

So for the Country attribute, I have this:

```
{[Sell To Customer].[Country Code].&[BE], [Sell To Customer].[Country Code].&[NL]}
```

Now when the Country Code attribute is "BE" then this user should only be able to access [Dim12 Name] with the value "FOOD". If the Country Code attribute is "NL" then he should see all possible values in the [Dim 12 Name] attribute.

Currently I have this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
IIF( [Sell To Customer].[Country Code].&[BE], {[Sell To Customer].[Dim12 Name].&[FOOD]},  IIF( [Sell To Customer].[Country Code].&[NL], {[Sell To Customer].[Dim12 Name].ALLMEMBERS},  "" ) )
```

Does anyone know another way or fix for my problem?

KR,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

```
exists( 
  [Sell To Customer].[Country Code].&[BE], 
  {[Sell To Customer].[Dim12 Name].&[FOOD]},  
  exists( 
    [Sell To Customer].[Country Code].&[NL], 
    {[Sell To Customer].[Dim12 Name]},  
    {} 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: I've tried to use this, but it's still showing only "Food" values for when I'm filtering on country code NL.